# Elastic Beanstalk: customize Puma configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, puma

The current Beanstalk solution stack for Ruby + Puma uses the configuration file at `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/pumaconf.rb` and ignores the `config/puma.rb` inside the Rails application directory.

I could override the file above with a custom one via `.ebextensions` but am hesitant because I'd like to avoid breakage in case the path to the PID or - more importantly - unix socket files changes in upcoming solution stack versions.

What is the best practice for customizing the Puma configuration on Beanstalk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use Ruby+Passenger, but it sounds similar enough to your situation. We need to customize the nginx configuration file stored at `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/nginx_config.erb`, so we do it via `.ebextensions` and `sed`.

Here's an example to get you started:

**.ebextensions/01-edit-nginx.config**

```
container_commands:
  01backup_config:
    command: "cp -n /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/nginx_config.erb /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/nginx_config.erb.original"
  02edit_config:
    command: "sh -c \"sed '/string_to_insert_text_after/ i\
\    text_to_be_inserted;' /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/nginx_config.erb.original > /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/nginx_config.erb\""
```

This will make a backup copy of the configuration file (without overwriting it if it already exists, thanks to the `-n` flag) and then insert the line "text_to_be_inserted" after the line "string_to_insert_text_after". You can pipe multiple `sed` commands together to insert multiple lines.

Answer (score 6):

On Amazon Linux 2, you can use `Procfile` to do this, e.g.

`web: puma -C /var/app/current/config/puma.rb`

See the docs at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ruby-platform-procfile.html for more information.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer

Comment: Thank you, not sure if @milgner is active, but the currently accepted answer is 1) about passenger and 2) ignores Procfile.